# Excel Macro for generating emails only works when IDE is open

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I've been looking for an answer for this for a few weeks, and it's driving me crazy:

I have a macro that copies specific cells to a new email in Outlook. It works perfectly if the IDE is open, but typically if it isn't it pastes the content into the current sheet instead of the new email. Even weirder is that sometimes it WILL work while the IDE is closed, but 99% of the time it won't, making this a nightmare to diagnose.

It's driving me crazy, you guys are my only hope!

```
Sub EmailReports()
    Dim rngSubject As Range
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngBody As Range
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    xRow = ActiveCell.Row
    RMName = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & xRow)
    LastTaskRow = Sheets(RMName).Range("A1")

    With Target
    Range("E" & xRow) = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY")
    End With



    Set rngTo = Range("C" & xRow)
    Set rngSubject = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("K4")
    Set rngBody = Worksheets(RMName).Range("D4:E" & LastTaskRow)

    rngBody.Copy


    With objMail
        .To = rngTo
        .Subject = rngSubject
        .Display
    End With

    SendKeys "^({v})", True

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing



End Sub
```

I tried adding Dmitry's suggestion, though I'm not sure I added it properly.

```
Sub EmailReports()
    Dim rngSubject As Range
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngBody As Range
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    xRow = ActiveCell.Row
    RMName = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & xRow)
    LastTaskRow = Sheets(RMName).Range("A1")

    With Target
    Range("E" & xRow) = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY")
    End With



    Set rngTo = Range("C" & xRow)
    Set rngSubject = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("K4")
    Set rngBody = Worksheets(RMName).Range("D4:E" & LastTaskRow)

    rngBody.Copy


    With objMail
        .To = rngTo
        .Subject = rngSubject
        .Display
    End With

    Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    ClipboardText = objHTML.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
    objMail.Body = rngBody.Text


    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Dmitry was on the right track by using an HTML file instead of a simple copy/SendKeys.

Here is the new code:

```
Sub EmailReports()
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

xRow = ActiveCell.Row
RMName = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & xRow)
LastTaskRow = Sheets(RMName).Range("A1")

With Target
Range("E" & xRow) = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY")
End With


Set rngTo = Range("C" & xRow)
Set rngSubject = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("K4")
Set rngBody = Worksheets(RMName).Range("D4:E" & LastTaskRow)

With objMail
    .To = rngTo
    .Subject = rngSubject
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rngBody)
    .Display
End With


Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing



End Sub
```

It is calling a function I found on Microsoft's website called "RangetoHTML":

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    ' Copy the range and create a workbook to receive the data.
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ' Publish the sheet to an .htm file.
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    ' Read all data from the .htm file into the RangetoHTML subroutine.
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    ' Close TempWB.
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Delete the htm file.
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using SendKeys (which will send the specified input to the foreground window, whatever it happens to be), paste the text using

```
Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
ClipboardText = objHTML.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
objMail.Body = ClipboardText
```

Or, even better, do not use clipboard at all and read the text of the current selection in Excel explicitly and set the Body property in Outlook:

```
objMail.Body = rngBody.Text
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Dmitry! I tried adding that in where SendKeys used to be. It's giving me an error now."Type Mismatch: Cannot coerce parameter. Outlook cannot translate your string." Am I adding it in the wrong space? Also, will .Text keep the formatting I had on the body cells?

Comment: You don't need to use both of my suggestions. Only one would do. The second one is better. Which line of your code raises the error?

Comment: I tried just replacing the SendKeys with your second suggestion. I get an error on that line saying "Run-time error: Type Mismatch: Cannot coerce parameter value. Outlook cannot translate your string." Could it be because it's selecting a range of cells and not a single value?

Comment: Can you insert the following line? What does it show? MsgBox TypeName(rngBody.Text)

Comment: Hmmm.. I am not an Excel expert.... Can you try the first suggestion (with the clipboard)?

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help, Dmitry. I finally figured it out - you got me on the right track!